# strtok() returning incorrect value in C99?

Tags: c, pointers, valgrind, c99

I'm running on a 32bit linux system using std c99 first off. So I have this code

```
char* tokPtr = strtok(expr, " ");
    while(tokPtr != NULL) {
            tokPtr = strtok(NULL, " ");
            puts(tokPtr);
            push(tokens, tokPtr);
    }
```

expr is a C string passed in as a parameter looking something like "1 2 +". And I'm just using puts for testing purposes. However, when I run valgrind with the --leak-check=full flag on it gives me an invalid read of size 1 for strlen in puts and ends with a seg fault. When I make tokPtr = "1"; and comment out the strtok() stuff, I run valgrind and no errors at all. I have no idea why this is happening and I could really use some help. Thanks.

Comment: My last resort would be to just loop strtok() and reset the string with the first part just chopped off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here:

```
while(tokPtr != NULL) {
    tokPtr = strtok(NULL, " ");
    puts(tokPtr);
```

you should be checking whether `tokPtr == NULL` *after* you call `strtok()`, not before. When `strtok()` does finally return `NULL`, as it will eventually, you will always pass `NULL` to `puts()` with this code, and that's giving you your problem.

You can just reorder, and change to:

```
char* tokPtr = strtok(expr, " ");
while(tokPtr != NULL) {
    puts(tokPtr);
    push(tokens, tokPtr);
    tokPtr = strtok(NULL, " ");
}
```

Also remember that `strtok()` modifies the string it works with and returns internal pointers to that string. You don't show your `push()` function, but unless the code is very simple, and your `expr` array always outlasts your stack, you're likely to run into problems pushing these pointers onto it. It may be better to `malloc()` some memory for each token and copy what `strtok()` returns into it, and then push those.

Comment: Okay, I understand, thank you for your help, It worked out nicely

Answer (score 1):

I know this is already answered, but for this very reason I recommend using strtok in a for() instead of a while(), since it natuarally has an initializer, test condition, and iterator.  For example:

```
for( char* tokPtr = strtok(expr, " ");
     tokPtr != NULL;
     tokPtr = strtok(NULL, " ") )
{
    puts(tokPtr);
    push(tokens, tokPtr);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is actually a really useful example